# Jquery select option append not working in IE

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, dropdown

I have used Jquery to append options to Infopath created select dropdown. It works in Firefox but it does not populate in IE. Below is the code used:

```
var newOption = $('<option value="'+val+'">'+val+'</option>');
$('select[originalid="V1_I1_D6"]').eq(0).append(newOption);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look at the html in IE and see if originalid is different that it is in firefox

Comment: No both are same

Comment: just hit this $('select[originalid="V1_I1_D6"]') in console tab in developer tool in IE. What does it return? Is it returning the dropdown control?

Comment: yes it is. returning the control

Comment: Now $('select[originalid="V1_I1_D6"]').eq(0) what is it returning?
After that run full command $('select[originalid="V1_I1_D6"]').eq(0).append(newOption); via developer tool and see if its append

Comment: it is appending when I run it through the console. But not working when I run script through external js file. I am attaching the file using the script editor

Comment: It should work if its responding in developer tool. check if all files like sp.js and init.js are loaded. I guess you need to call that specifically in your script like jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', yourfunction);
});

Comment: the originalid is same for a dropdown in another page. does that make any impact? I use different js file for two separate pages

Comment: I'm executing the code using ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
Still no luck.. Its kind of fluctuating. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: write everything in window.load

Comment: no luck. Its still the same

Comment: could you try hardcoding the 'val' in above code and try? it could be value of val that is not populating in IE properly because of some other code?

Comment: Yes I did hardcoded some value. It doesn't do anything. I even tried removing some options from the select element, still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Below snippet is working fine for IE8 and later version.

```
$("#ddlDomain option").eq(0).before($("<option></option>").val("").text("--Select--"));
```

If you want to show selected option which you have added by above statement then you need to add one more statement as below:

```
$('#ddlDomain').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Hope this helps you...

Happy Coading :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already tried to put your JavaScript code inside *window.onload* or 
*$(document).ready(...)* events without success, then you could try to call your function in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(retrieveListItems);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're likely facing is that the element that you're attempting to select via jQuery here is being written into the DOM by some other script that's running on the page as your code is working just fine from the console but not in `ready()`

In all honesty the easiest solution is likely a *dirty hack* to delay your script for a short period of time. Give this a whirl:

```
$().ready(function(){
  function insertNewElement() {
    var newOption = $('<option value="'+val+'">'+val+'</option>');
    $('select[originalid="V1_I1_D6"]').eq(0).append(newOption);
  }
  window.setTimeout(insertNewElement, 1000);
});
```

All it's doing is waiting 1000ms to execute your code. You may need to fiddle with the timing and it's not going to be 100% reliable. For example if your user has a horrible internet connection and the way that the form you want to manipulate is loading data after `ready()` fires and it takes longer than 1000ms to return it's going to fail. 
That said for many environments this is going to be good enough.

Comment: Even I thought the same. I delayed the script for like 2 secs. It works fine sometimes but mostly it doesn't populate.

Comment: So it works sometimes at 2s but never if you don't delay? Sounds like this is on the right track. bump it up some more are re-try?

Answer (score 0):

I know that in older versions of IE there were all kinds of issue modifying a select's options. This technique has worked for me instead of creating new Options and appending those

```
$('#selector')
   .append($('<option></option>')
   .attr("value",item.value)
   .text(item.Title)
```